# Haskell: No instance of (Num ()) - defining my own monadic loop

Tags: loops, haskell, types, monads, higher-order-functions

I am attempting this exercise in Haskell wiki:  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Higher-order_functions

> The following exercise combines what you have learned about higher
>   order functions, recursion and I/O. We are going to recreate what is
>   known in imperative languages as a *for* loop. Implement a function
>
> ```
> for :: a -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> (a -> IO ()) -> IO () 
> for i p f job = -- ???
> ```

so far I have:

```
-- for : init value, end condition function, increment function, IO function, 
--       returns IO action

generate :: a -> (a->Bool) -> (a->a) -> [a]
generate s cnd incr = if (cnd s) then [] else [s] ++ generate (incr s) cnd incr

printToList  = do
               u <- print 1
               v <- print 2
               return [u,v]

ioToASingle :: [IO a] -> IO [a]
ioToASingle (x:xs) = do
                 x' <- x
                 return [x']

sequenceIO :: [IO a] -> IO [a]
sequenceIO [] = return []
sequenceIO (x:xs) = do
                     x' <- x
                     xs' <- sequenceIO xs
                     return ([x'] ++ xs')

for::a->(a->Bool)->(a->a)->(a->IO())->IO()
for s cnd incr ioFn = sequence_ (map (ioFn) (generate s cnd incr))

for'::a->(a->Bool)->(a->a)->(a->IO a)->IO [a]
for' s cnd incr ioFn = sequenceIO (map (ioFn) (generate s cnd incr))
```

`for` works OK:

```
for 1 (\i->i==10) (\i->i+1) (print)
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

`for'` gets an error:

```
*Main> for' 1 (\i->i==10) (\i->i+1) (print)

<interactive>:323:6: error:
    • No instance for (Num ()) arising from the literal ‘1’
    • In the first argument of ‘for'’, namely ‘1’
      In the expression: for' 1 (\ i -> i == 10) (\ i -> i + 1) (print)
      In an equation for ‘it’:
          it = for' 1 (\ i -> i == 10) (\ i -> i + 1) (print)
*Main>
```

I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: The type of `(print)` is `Show a => a -> IO ()`, not `Show a => a -> IO a`. You need to combine it with something else to make it return the input back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you wrote:

```
    for' :: a -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a ) -> (a -> IO a ) -> IO [a]
    for'    s    cnd            incr         ioFn         =  sequenceIO (map (ioFn) ...

*Main> for' 1    (\i->i==10)    (\i->i+1)    (print     )      
            a                                (a -> IO ())
                                             ------------
            ()                                      a ~ ()
```

Thus `1 :: (Num a) => a ~ (Num ()) => ()`. But there's no `Num` instance for the type `()`.

This is GHC's roundabout way of telling you, you need a function of type `a -> IO a`, not `a -> IO ()`.

Hindley-Milner allows unification with a "narrower" type, but here it would be better if it weren't -- the error message would be much clearer.

In any case it is easy to conjure up your own *value*–returning *print*, like

```
myprint :: a -> IO a
myprint x = do { print x      -- or,  print x >> return x
               ; return x 
               }
```

Comment: @luqui thanks; white space is an important tool. In Lisp, too.

Answer (score 0):

sequenceIO return type is IO [a], but ioFn (as in the definition of for') is "print" which returns IO(). You need ioFn to return IO a, so that return of sequenceIO will be IO [a].

e.g. try "return" instead of "print" and then print the value. "return" is a function in haskell which simply converts the argument passed into monad, in this case IO monad.

```
main = do p <- for' 1 (\i->i==10) (\i->i+1) (return) 
         print(p)
```

This will print simply list of 1 to 9 numbers.

Or

```
p :: Int -> IO [Int]
p x =  for' 1 (\i->i==x) (\i->i+1) (return)

main = do y <- p 10
         print (y)
```

Comment: you meant "`ioFn` which returns `IO a`".

Comment: also, your indentation is wrong. you need either to correct it, or add explicit `{ ; }` delimiters, or *both*.